# What control to use for an overlay GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I am trying to design a GUI and before I start, I would like some opinions on what type of controls I should use.

I am designing a GUI that will be used for novice users. The GUI will present 4-5 options in large clickable buttons. When the user clicks a button, the same GUI window will then display the deeper level context.

For example, one of the button is called "Users", and when the user click on the button, the entire GUI will be refreshed and present 4 additional buttons that says "New User", "Log in", "Delete Users" etc etc. each time a user clicks on a button, the GUI refreshes and present users with a new sets of button.

What is one of the better way to go about designing such GUI? I was thinking about using multiple TabControl and just hiding them/showing them depending on what button is clicked.

any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Awesome.  Any rough diagrams to illustrate your idea?

Comment: Yes. Similiar to when you first open a chrome tab. there are webpage snapshots displayed. My GUI will have a window that displays those snapshots, when you click on one, then additional snapshots will replace the current ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page:

> The Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) supports browser-style
>   navigation that can be used in two types of applications: standalone
>   applications and XAML browser applications (XBAPs).

You can use the WPF to navigate to new pages when the user clicks a button. You can read more about it in the same page where I got that quote from.